# unrecognized selector sent to instance - Swift 4 only

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, selector, swift4

I'm having trouble understanding what this error means. My app was working fine until I migrated up to Swift 4. Now I'm getting this `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` error when trying to open several of my view controllers. I didn't get any of these errors in Swift 3.2. The numberOfRowsInSection method has been implemented in all cases, and appears fine. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

> 2017-11-26 10:21:04.973523-0600 Y2GOsp[27701:6382461]
>   -[Y2GOsp.ClientDetailViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa51c89f000 2017-11-26
>   10:21:43.328635-0600 Y2GOsp[27701:6382461] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[Y2GOsp.ClientDetailViewController
>   tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x7fa51c89f000'

numberOfRowsInSection implementations:

Example 1:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

Example 2:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dayAppoints.count
}
```

Comment: Add your `numberOfRowsInSection` implementation to the question.

Comment: Are you aware that you wrote `tableview:…` instead of `tableView:…`?

Comment: Just a typo. I have updated it. @vacawama, I have added examples of implementations for two of the viewControllers that are failing.

Comment: Is `ClientDetailViewController` a subclass of `UITableViewController`?

Comment: @vacawama, no, it's a subclass of a subclass of UIViewController.

Comment: Does adding `@objc` before the func declaration make it work?

Comment: @vacawma, yes, it does!! I'm happy, but confused. I thought I got all the instances where there was a warning about that, but I must have missed a few. Post your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Does your class state its conformance to `UITableViewDataSource`? If it does, Swift should infer (and require) that your implementation(s) of the `@objc` protocol requirements are also `@objc`. It would help if you could provide some more context.

Comment: @vacawama, good catch! In the few instances where this was happening, I had forgotten to add `UITableViewDataSource`. With that added, I no longer need the `@objc`.

Comment: That would explain it.  I'm surprised that Swift didn't complain when you assigned the delegate.

Comment: what to do in case @objc still results in the same error?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

@Hamish identified the issue in his comment.  You forgot to add `UITableViewDataSource` to your `class` declaration.  Because of that, your data source methods were not exposed to Objective-C.

My suggestion to try adding `@objc` to the methods confirmed the issue.

The reason this worked in Swift 3 was that all methods of classes that derived from `NSObject` (which `UIViewController` does) were available to Objective-C.

In Swift 4 [(due to SE-0160)](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0160-objc-inference.md), it is necessary to explicitly tag functions with `@objc` that will be called through a selector unless you are overriding a function that is so marked in the base class, or in this case if the functions satisfy the requirement of an `@objc` protocol definition.

Comment: In my case it was occurring because I forgot to change Module in Custom Class (Main.storyboard) because I reused a project for a new one

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I followed vacawama suggestions. But instead of adding @objc before every delegated method (I find the @objc tags very ugly), I made my ViewController implement the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate protocols (I have a generic VC containing a UITableView) and assigned my ViewController to his tableView explicitely as a datasource and delegate:

```
self.tableView.delegate = self
self.tableView.dataSource = self
```

and it works like a charm, without ugly @objc tags.
In fact, I originally assigned the delegate and datasource to the tableView using the InterfaceBuilder (via ctrl + click)